# How to find group of key pair in python

Tags: python, performance, sorting

I have Dict :

```
resultDict = {"aaa10" : 10, "eee343", 88 ,"aaa15" : 40,"bbb60" : 10,"aaa13" : 80,"bbb60" : 10,"aaa30" : 50,"ccc99" : 100, "aaa56" : 10,"ccc67" : 10,"aaa78" : 40, "ddd78" :88 , "eee343" : 88 }
```

I'd like to custom group it by dict key & first 3 letter is fixed as a pattern.

Desire Output :

```
Group,1            # For Group-1 include eee* and ccc* pattern with value and so on
 eee343, 88
 eee100, 10
 ...
 ccc*, <value>
Group,2
 bbb* <value>
Group,3
 ddd* <value>
 aaa*, <value>
```

My code:

```
print("Group","1")
for key,value in resultDict.items():
  if re.findall ("eee", key) or ("ccc", key):
     print(key,value)

print("Group","2")
for key,value in resultDict.items():
  if re.findall ("bbb", key):
     print(key,value)

print("Group","3")
for key,value in resultDict.items():
  if re.findall ("ddd", key) or ("aaa", key):
     print(key,value)
```

But I have around 10 group and `Dict` contain many pair, it's take too much time to run and code is also no looks good. I'm find best solution in python to do quickly and better way !

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `re.findall ("ddd", key) or ("aaa", key)` to mean? Why? How?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel with this, Finding pattern and print it.

Comment: When the code `re.findall ("ddd", key) or ("aaa", key)` runs, how many times do you expect the `re.findall` function to run? Why? How? In your own words, in Python, what does the `or` keyword mean, and how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function for making a group and run it multiple times:

```
resultDict = {"aaa10" : 10, "eee343": 88 ,"aaa15" : 40,"bbb60" : 10,"aaa13" : 80,"bbb60" : 10,"aaa30" : 50,"ccc99" : 100, "aaa56" : 10,"ccc67" : 10,"aaa78" : 40, "ddd78" :88 , "eee343" : 88 }

def group_finder(group_index,resultDict,keys):
    
    group_list=[]
    
    for key in keys:
        group_list.extend(
        list(filter(lambda string: string.startswith(key),resultDict))
                )
    
    print('Group',group_index)
    for key in group_list:
        print(key,',',resultDict[key])
    
group_finder(1,resultDict,['eee','ccc'])
group_finder(2,resultDict,['bbb'])
group_finder(3,resultDict,['ddd','aaa'])
```

which prints

```
Group 1
eee343 , 88
ccc99 , 100
ccc67 , 10
Group 2
bbb60 , 10
Group 3
ddd78 , 88
aaa10 , 10
aaa15 , 40
aaa13 , 80
aaa30 , 50
aaa56 , 10
aaa78 , 40
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve:

```
import pandas as pd


d = {"aaa10" : 10, "eee343": 88 ,"aaa15" : 40,"bbb60" : 10,"aaa13" : 80,"bbb60" : 10,"aaa30" : 50,"ccc99" : 100, "aaa56" : 10,"ccc67" : 10,"aaa78" : 40, "ddd78" :88 , "eee343" : 88 }
df = pd.DataFrame([d]).T.reset_index()

map_dict = {
    "eee" : 1,
    "ccc" : 1,
    "bbb" : 2,
    "ddd" : 3,
    "aaa" : 3
}
df['index'].astype(str).str[:3].map(map_dict)
for index,(grp,x) in enumerate(df.groupby(df['index'].astype(str).str[:3].map(map_dict)),1):
    print('Group', index)
    for k,v in x.to_dict(orient='split')['data']:
        print(k,v)
```

**output:**

```
Group 1
eee343 88
ccc99 100
ccc67 10
Group 2
bbb60 10
Group 3
aaa10 10
aaa15 40
aaa13 80
aaa30 50
aaa56 10
aaa78 40
ddd78 88
```

Comment: that is helpful but wish to `eee` and `ccc` pattern must be in group-1 and `bbb` in group-2 and `aaa` and `ddd`  in group-3 and so on...group <number> is title of set of key,value for each pair, you may check me desire output. I think, small modification require which very helpful to me

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure Python solution that doesn't require Pandas:

```py
def getGroups(dictionary: dict, groups: list, subStringLen = 3) -> dict:
    return [(dict([(k, v) for k, v in dictionary.items() if k[:subStringLen] == group])) for group in groups]
```

Which you could use like:

```py
resultDict = {"aaa10" : 10, "eee343": 88, "aaa15" : 40,"bbb60" : 10,"aaa13" : 80,"bbb60" : 10,"aaa30" : 50,"ccc99" : 100, "aaa56" : 10,"ccc67" : 10,"aaa78" : 40, "ddd78" :88 , "eee343" : 88 }

print("Group 1")
print(getGroups(resultDict, ["eee", "ccc"]))

print("Group 2")
print(getGroups(resultDict, ["bbb"]))

print("Group 3")
print(getGroups(resultDict, ["ddd", "aaa"]))
```

Returns

```
Group 1
[{'eee343': 88}, {'ccc99': 100, 'ccc67': 10}]
Group 2
[{'bbb60': 10}]
Group 3
[{'ddd78': 88}, {'aaa10': 10, 'aaa15': 40, 'aaa13': 80, 'aaa30': 50, 'aaa56': 10, 'aaa78': 40}]
```

This answer uses nested list comprehension but all it does is for each group, searches the given dictionary for keys that have the substring of the group. To get the exact output you're after, you could then flatten the list.